# how to set background image in css at MVC4

Tags: css, model-view-controller

i want to set image as background  in **CSS** at **MVC4**  i have to tried the code below

```
background: url('@Url.Content("~/Images/seizurerobots.gif")');

 background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/Images/seizurerobots.gif")');

   background: url("Images/seizurerobots.gif");

  background: url("../Images/seizurerobots.gif");
```

but am not able to acheive if anyone have a solution plzz share

Thanks...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all Your above Mentioned Tags top two tags will not work  as  you are mixing  two concepts, in css simply give the url of image

```
 background: url("imagepath");

  background-image: url("imagepath");
```

The above are ok and should work please check you code and see weather the image url is working or not, you can check it in element inspector of browser